# " 'homePage' is defined but never used no-unused-vars" I imported the homePage component and used it still getting no-unused-vars

Tags: reactjs

I imported the homePage component and used it still getting no-unused-vars

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKrf5.png)

[homPage.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FjOg.png)

I am not abble to import my component and my react page is showing a complete blank! Anyone please help me out :( I can't find the error.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The names of React components must start with an uppercase letter, otherwise they will be treated as regular HTML elements.

If you open your browser console, you should see a warning that tells you exacly this: `Warning: The tag <homePage> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.`.